# Video call with android stack SIP

Tags: android, video, sip

I am developing an application where I want to create a audio or video call between two user on android platform with stack SIP classes. I have referred other question on SO but I hardly find any solution for the Problem. As mentioned on Android docs it possible to achieve this using the method open() of SipManager but I hardly get any where near to this for video call. I guess we need to use getOfferSessionDescription() to get RTP to stream the video. If anyone has done this or knows how I would be able to achieve this it would be very helpful.

Note:I don't wish to use any 3rd party lib. i stirctly wish to use as mentioned in the doc
[open()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html)

Comment: I'd suggest to have a look at the way it is done in sipdroid source. sipdroid is an opensource sip client for android

Comment: @mangusta that's pretty outdated code. Most of the classes are not available.